# ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth,

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I'm working with the DotNetOpenAuth controls and on my ASPX pages in source view I have a blue squiggly line under the @Page directive with the following error.

> ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth,
>   Version=3.2.0.9177, Cultur=neutral,
>   PublicToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one
>   of its dependencies.  Failed to grant
>   minimum permission requests.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)

The controls also do not render in the Designer, instead I get an "Error Creating Control" message however the project compiles and runs just fine.

Anyone know what is going on?

Side note:

The project is on a remote server and I'm accessing it over a network share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [blog](http://marcoscavaleiro.blogspot.com/2006/11/failed-to-grant-minimum-permission.html) post.

You get the error because your trust level isn't correct.

Comment: I was hoping there was an easier way than downloading and reinstalling the SDK but the download finally finished and it worked. :)

Comment: That link is now dead; here is an Internet Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150102105855/http://marcoscavaleiro.blogspot.com/2006/11/failed-to-grant-minimum-permission.html